# Ember: Why does computed not fire when the observer does?

Tags: ember.js

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around this - I'm working with inherited legacy code, and while this seems like it should be very simple, it's anything but.

In this app/pods/application/route.js, there's a "welcome pack" object that's grabbed by the server, as part of that, there's a setWp() method called on the welcome-pack service, which sets the 'wp' value on that same service.  (Yes, I know you can probably set the value on the service directly, with "this.wp.set('wp', welcomePack)" but as I said: inherited legacy code.) Point is, that should trigger the change in the value. My observer for wp.wp is firing, but NOT my computeds based on wp.wp.  Any clues?

```
// app/pods/application/route.js
wp: inject('welcome-pack'),
model(){
  return this.store.findAll('welcome-pack').then((welcomePack) => {
  this.wp.setWp(welcomePack);
})
}



// app/pods/welcome-pack/service.js
import Service from '@ember/service';
export default Service.extend({
  wp: null,
  setWp(wp){ // <-- called when the model loads from the ajax request
    this.set('wp', wp)
  }
})

// app/pods/application/controller.js
import Controller from "@ember/controller";
import { inject } from "@ember/service";
import { computed, observer } from "@ember/object";

export default Controller.extend({
  wp: inject("welcome-pack"),
  init(){
    console.log('this.wp', this.wp) // <- logs service as class
    console.log('this.wp.wp', this.wp.wp) // <-logs null
    setTimeout(() => {
      // set for after the ajax call has been made and setWp() has been called. 
      console.log('this.wp', this.wp) //<- logs service as class
      console.log('this.wp.wp', this.wp.wp) //<- logs object as class
    }, 2000)
  },
  obsWPChanges: observer('wp', function(){
    console.log('wp changed'); // <-- never executes (don't expect it to)
  }),
  obsWPWPChanges: observer('wp.wp', function(){
    console.log('wp.wp changed') //<-- executes (as expected) when setWP() is called
  }),
  primaryColor: computed("wp.wp", function() {
    console.log("this.wp.primaryColor", this.wp.primaryColor) // <-- does not execute
    return this.wp.wp.primaryColor || "#37b3c0";
  }),
  secondaryColor: computed("wp.wp", function() {
    return this.wp.wp.secondaryColor || "#38a0d0"; // <-- does not execute
  })
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ember, computed properties are lazily evaluated. So, until they're referenced, they're never executed.

Observers, on the other hand, always fire when they're dependent keys change. The behavior that you show above is perfectly explainable, assuming `primaryColor` and `secondaryColor` are never referenced by this point in time. Taken from the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/computed-properties/):

> A computed property will only recompute its value when it is consumed.
>   Properties are consumed in two ways:
>
> By being accessed, for example `ironMan.fullName`
>
> By being referenced in
>   a handlebars template that is currently being rendered, for example
>   `{{ironMan.fullName}}` Outside of those two circumstances the code in
>   the property will not run, even if one of the property's dependencies
>   are changed.

I remember your long rant from the Ember subreddit, hope you're having a better time. I highly recommend giving the docs a thorough one over now that you've accumulated some experience.

Comment: You're right, and I wasn't referencing primaryColor or secondaryColor in my template (mostly because I was waiting for this to work first, before applying it to the template, because that's what good programs do - go step-by-step - rather than all at once.)

If anything, my experiences with Ember have only gotten worse, and I think I've learned enough about it by now to conclude that Ember is dying for a reason. I've been assured I'd be more proficient given time. I could be more proficient in anything given time, it doesn't make it any better or less frustrating to work with. (see: PHP)

Comment: well even if Ember makes you bitter, you can still accept the answer ;)

Comment: Also, straight-up dev-to-dev, Ember's not that hard if you already know ES6. The guide would take you at most an hour to read, 2 if you went along side it and did some practical examples.

Comment: @BrianBoyko ember is not dying - but the teams have understood this problems. Checkout the [keynote of emberfest this year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRzmDobMZ_Q). Exactly this will change in near future. However its reasonable that getters are not called before you not use them. This means you don't need to do heavy computations when you don't need to show the data.

Comment: @BrianBoyko did you see the replies here? https://www.reddit.com/r/emberjs/comments/9woqn7/xpost_stack_overflow_ember_why_does_computed_not/

The answer here is very well explained.
FWIW, I know learning new things can be hard, if they don't immediately mesh with your mental model. We're here to help. Just please try to be patient with yourself.